# Wpftoolkit 2008 Reference error

Tags: wpf

my code is given below

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="QueuedTradesGrid"
                      Sorting="QueuedTradesGridc_Sorting"
                       TargetUpdated="QueuedTradesGridc_TargetUpdated"
                       Loaded="QueuedTradesGridc_Loaded"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding QueuedTradesCollection, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" Width="40"/>
            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn  SortMemberPath="Date"   Header="Date" Width="80" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}"  DataFieldBinding="{Binding Date}"/>
            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="TradeID" Header="TradeID" Width="120" SortDirection="Ascending" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" DataFieldBinding="{Binding TradeID}" />
```

I got the following  error from wpf toolkit 2008

The property 'DataFieldBinding' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit'.

Comment: So there is obviously no property `DataFieldBinding` in those classes. Why do you think they should exist?

Comment: it compiled without error previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did rename the `DataFieldBinding`-Property to just `Binding`:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/22/wpf-datagrid-and-the-wpftoolkit-have-released.aspx (Look under **Breaking changes and how to update CTP code to v1**).